# Error 8921 running DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption, dbcc

DBCC CHECKDB shows following error message in my sql server 2008 R2 database

Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.

What is the solution?

Comment: Is that the only message it returns? How long does it run for before it stops? And what happens if you run DBCC CHECKALLOC on the same database?

Comment: It shows following messages after running DBCC CHECKALLOC.                 Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.
CHECKALLOC found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'OldLotus'.

Answer (score 3):

Given that DBCC CHECKALLOC fails too, with no corruption messages, your database has corrupt metadata and you need to restore from your backups (the first thing it does is run some basic checks on the three critical system tables it needs, and if they're badly broken, it will fail with message 8921). You have no other choice here - you can't run repair as you can't get DBCC CHECKDB to run.

It's possible you could narrow down which system table is corrupt using DBCC CHECKTABLE on successive object IDs from sys.objects, and then manually edit around the corruption, but that's very advanced and has a very low chance of success.

If you don't have any backups, you're going to have to create a new database and then export all the schemas and data into the new database.